# How can I get the selected value with jQuery Selectr?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plugin using multi select from this web site:
http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Pretty-jQuery-Searchable-Multi-Select-Box-For-Bootstrap-selectr.html

But, I have a slight problem retrieving the selected value when I select the element because the plugin adds a selected class but not a `selected` attribute. The render of the plugin is like the code below.

```
<select name="demo" id="multiple" multiple="" style="display: none;">
   <option data-selectr-color="rgb(0, 163, 0)" value="toto">toto</option>
   <option data-selectr-color="rgb(0, 163, 0)" value="Hermes"> Hermes </option>
   <option data-selectr-color="rgb(0, 163, 0)" value="test"> test </option>     
</select>

<ul class="list-group" style="max-height: 100px;">
   <li class="list-group-item undefined **selected**">
       <div class="color-code undefined" style="background-color: rgb(0, 163,        0);">/div>
       <div class="option-name" title=""> toto</div>
       <div class="add-remove undefined">×</div></li>
  <li class="list-group-item undefined">
       <div class="color-code undefined" style="background-color: rgb(0, 163, 0);"></div>
       <div class="option-name" title=""> Hermes </div>

$(document).ready(function () {
  function displayVals() {

  if($("li").hasClass("selected")){
    alert("selectionne")
  }
//$('div ul li[class="list-group-item selected"] div[class="option-name"]').text()
  var multipleValues = $('div ul li[class="list-group-item undefined selected"] div[class="option-name"]').text();
  $( "p" ).html(   " <b>Multiple:</b> " + multipleValues );
}
$("list-group-item undefined").change(function(){
    alert("tot");
});
displayVals();
});
```

When I click, I want it call the values of multi select and get the selected value on the console. When I select one value, it doesn't add a multi values.